# Compute the minimal polynomial of $u$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ without using cyclotomic polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $k\in \Bbb Z\setminus 7\Bbb Z$ and $a_k=\frac{2k\pi}{7}$. Compute the minimal polynomial of $u=$ over $\Bbb{Q}$

The "natural" (in my opinion) way to solve this problem, requires the use of $\Phi_7(t)=t^6+t^5+t^4+t^3+t^2+t+1$, the seventh cyclotomic polynomial, since it has the complex number $e^{2k\pi/7}$ as root. Then, noticing that

$$u=e^{2k\pi i/7}+e^{-2k\pi i/7}$$
and dividing $\Phi_7(t)$ by $t^3$, doing some calculations result that a polynomial which has $u$ as one of its roots is

$$P(t)=t^3+t^2-2t-1$$
But $P(t)$ is monic and has no roots in $\Bbb{Z}$, hence it is irreducible, so it has to be the minimal polynomial of $u$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.

However, I'm not entirely happy with this answer. It feels that there is a simpler way to get to the same result, or at least to find the degree of the required polynomial. I'm thinking that somehow, it might be related to the fact that the $n$-th roots of unity form under multiplication a cyclic group of order $n$. So my question would be the following:

> Is there another way to solve this problem (if not, a way to calculate the degree of the minimal polynomial) without using cyclotomic polynomials?

As always, any answer would be highly appreciate, and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $u$ is the real part of $e^{i(2\pi/7)}$. Let $w=2\pi/7$ and note that $$1+\cos{w}+\cos2w+\dotsb+\cos6w=0.$$ because of the identity

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \cos(kx+y)=\frac{\cos(\frac{n}{2}x+y)\sin(\frac{n+1}{2}x)}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}$$
Then $\cos{w}=\cos6w$, while $\cos{2w}=\cos{5w}$, and $\cos{3w}=\cos{4w}$.

It follows that $$1+2\cos{w}+2\cos{2w}+2\cos{3w}=0.$$ or equivalently
$$-1-4\cos{w}+4\cos^2{w}+8\cos^3{w}=0.$$ 
This gives a polynomial of which $\cos{w}$ is a root.

Comment: Thank for the answer! But could you please explain where did you derive the first equation $1+\cos w+\cos 2w + \dots +\cos 7w =0$ if not by the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_7(t)$? And didn't we get different minimal polynomials?

Comment: One way to derive the identity would be to use the cyclotomic polynomial, evaluate at $e^{i(2\pi/7)}$, use DeMoivre's formula and take real parts, so in a way I did use these polynomails. If you want to avoid using these polynomials you can use a trig identity.

Comment: I think your polynomial is the minimal polynomial of $2\cos(2\pi/7)$

Comment: You're right, I mistyped the qeustion, it should indeed be $2\cos (2\pi /7)$. Is there any way to solve it using your argument?

Comment: Forget  the last question, and thanks again for your answer!